# Multi Column Indexes with Order By and OR clause

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have below query to fetch list of tickets.

```
EXPLAIN select * from ticket_type
                where ticket_type.event_id='89898'
                and ticket_type.active=true
                and (ticket_type.is_unlimited = true OR ticket_type.number_of_sold_tickets < ticket_type.number_of_tickets)
                order by ticket_type.ticket_type_order
```

I have created below indexes but not working.

1. Index on (ticket_type_order,event_id,is_unlimited,active)
2. Index on (ticket_type_order,event_id,active,number_of_sold_tickets,number_of_tickets).

Comment: If anything, `ticket_type_order` needs to come last so that Postgres can traverse the index on the `where` conditions and then get the rows in the right order. `number_of_sold_tickets < number_of_tickets` will be very hard though, I doubt that's indexable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect index for this query would be

```
CREATE INDEX ON ticket_type (event_id, ticket_type_order)
   WHERE active AND (is_unlimited OR number_of_sold_tickets < number_of_tickets);
```

Of course, a partial index like that might only be useful for this specific query.

If the `WHERE` conditions from the index definition are not very selective, or a somewhat slower execution is also acceptable, you can omit parts of or the whole `WHERE` clause. That makes the index more widely useful.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the table and usual query result? The server is usually smart enough and disables indexes, if it expects to return more than the half of the table.

Index makes no sense, if the result is rather small. If the server has - let say - 1000 records after several filtration steps, the server stops using indexes. It is cheaper the finish the query using CPU, then loading an index from HDD. As result, indexes are never applied to small tables.

`Order by` is applied at the very end of the query processing. The first field in the index should be one of the fields from the `where` filter.

Boolean fields are seldom useful in the index. It has only two possible values. Index should be created for fields with a lot of different values.

Avoid `or` filtering. It is easy in your case. Put a very big number into `number_of_tickets`, if the tickets are unlimited.

The better index in your case would be just `event_id`. If the database server supports functional indexes, then you can try to add `number_of_tickets - number_of_sold_tickets`. Rewrite the statement as `where number_of_tickets - number_of_sold_tickets > 0`

UPDATE: Postgresql calls it "Index on Expression":

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html